# Is using ‘down’ with ‘descend’ acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> A cascading silence that descends down the phone line.

Comment: Its *grammatically* correct. There's nothing wrong with using *descend* with a preposition — consider *descended to the, descended through the, descended from the*. However, it's redundant, and thus should be avoided.

Comment: In this rare case, *down* is less redundant than it seems. Down, here, means running along the phone wires, as opposed to descending *not upwards*.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to prove a negative, though no example of a prepositional phrase following 'descend/s/ed/ing' I've found in online dictionaries is headed by 'down' ... and there are no examples of '... descended down.' etc.

> - [T] *Jane descended the stairs slowly in her wedding gown.* {Prepositional phrase incidental to the present discussion; references 'Jane'.}
> - [I] *The path descends to the valley below.* {PP directional, hereafter 'D'}

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/descend)

> - *descended from the platform* {D; showing starting point}
> - *reporters descended on the candidate* {D, metaphorical}
> - *the road descends to the river* {D}
> - [*The plane descended onto the runway*] {EA; D}
> - *a hawk descending upon its prey* {D}
> - *descended to poverty* {D, metaphorical}
> - *The stairs descended into the tunnel.* {D}
> - *He descended into a deep depression.* {D, metaphorical}
> - *a desk that has descended [with]in the family* {locative, L}
> - *Alone and without a rope, he descended along a series of treacherous ledges* {D/L}
> - [*the head was not fully descended within the pelvis at the start of labour*] {EA; L}
> - [*He descended along with Hilary*] {EA; PP incidental}

[[Merriam-Webster except where indicated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/descend)]

..................

[Maeve Maddox, at Daily Writing Tips](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/preposition-mistakes-5-descend-discuss-return/), does label the usage unacceptable:

> One kind of preposition error is to follow a verb with a preposition
> when one is not needed.
>
> **descend**
>
> - INCORRECT: Sunita Gale and her husband descend down Highclere Castle’s majestic staircase. [Caption, Today site.]
> - CORRECT : Sunita Gale and her husband descend Highclere Castle’s majestic staircase.
>
> *Descend* is a [usually; EA] transitive verb that means “to move from a higher to a lower position.” The idea of down is included in the
> verb descend [so a directional down-phrase is redundant, and better avoided].

Though admittedly, there may well be some examples of 'descended down ...' to be found on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is redundancy in the written down words you wrote down. (Heh heh.) It's not wrong but it sounds a little weird.

But the reason it sounds weird isn't the redundancy. It's the join of "cascade" with "descends." "Descend" is too weak for "cascade."

Try one of these instead.

> A cascading silence that *tumbles* down the phone line.
> A cascading silence that *lurches* down the phone line.
> A cascading silence that *floods* down the phone line.

Or pick a word that works in your context.

Comment: Does silence usually tumble or lurch? It tends to fall or descend.

Comment: @StuartF It does not usually cascade either.